# Strange JSON behavior?

Tags: ruby, json

I'm trying to convert an object to JSON and then parse it again.  The problem is, when I parse the JSON string I'm left with a Hash and not my original object.  I found this simple example at [json.rubyforge.com](http://flori.github.com/json/) and tried it:

```
require 'json'

class Range
  def to_json(*a)
    {
      'json_class'   => self.class.name,
      'data'         => [ first, last, exclude_end? ]
    }.to_json(*a)
  end

  def self.json_create(o)
    new(*o['data'])
  end
end

puts JSON.parse((1..10).to_json) == (1..10)
```

It fails as well, returning `false`.  Looking further it doesn't seem that `json_create` is being called.

At this point I'm figuring I have to be missing something dead simple or I've run into a bug somewhere.  I'm using Ruby 1.9.3.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I tried same in `1.9.3`. `JSON.parse((1..10).to_json) == (1..10)` is giving `true`

Comment: `2.0.0` version works fine returning `true` as well.

Comment: I also just ran this code on 1.9.3 and it is working famously. 1) Do you have any other libraries being included? 2) Exactly what version of ruby? 1.9.3-p385? p392? There have been security problems with the features of the json library that you are using, so it may have been updated and work slightly differently depending on what version of ruby and/or the JSON gem you have installed.

Comment: I'm using 1.9.3-p392 and json 1.7.7 with rvm.

Comment: Ok, I downgraded to Ruby 1.9.3 p385 and it's working...  Thanks for the replies all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This change in behavior in p392 is due to a [security fix](https://github.com/flori/json/commit/d0a62f3ced7560daba2ad546d83f0479a5ae2cf2). See the [p392 release announcement](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/22/json-dos-cve-2013-0269/) for more details.

Your code works with the addition of the `:create_additions` option in your call to `JSON.parse`:

```
require 'json'

class Range
  def to_json(*a)
    {
      'json_class'   => self.class.name,
      'data'         => [ first, last, exclude_end? ]
    }.to_json(*a)
  end

  def self.json_create(o)
    new(*o['data'])
  end
end

puts JSON.parse((1..10).to_json, :create_additions => true) == (1..10)
```