# Ruby 1.9.3 JSON Parsing

Tags: ruby, json, rvm

I'm encountering a weird problem when parsing JSON with `Ruby 1.9.3-p392` under RVM on CentOS 6.4. Instead of decoding embedded objects into their appropriate Ruby classes, it's just loading the object as a hash. In `Ruby 1.9.3-p194` it works correctly.

Take the following sample:

```
require 'json'

class TestMe
    attr_accessor :me
    def initialize(option_hash = nil)
        if option_hash
            @me = option_hash['me']
        end
        @me ||= "Hello"
    end

    def to_json(*a)
        {
            JSON.create_id => self.class.name,
            'data' => {
                "me" => @me
            }
        }.to_json(*a)
    end

    def self.json_create(o)
        new(o['data'])
    end
end

t = TestMe.new
t.me = "foo"
t2 = JSON.parse(t.to_json)
puts t2
```

If I run this on `Ruby 1.9.3-p194`, it outputs the following:

```
#<TestMe:0x00000001c877f0>
```

If I run the same snippet on `Ruby 1.9.3-p392`, it outputs the following:

```
{"json_class"=>"TestMe", "data"=>{"me"=>"foo"}}
```

The behavior in `p194` is what I *expect* and what the documentation implies. Why isn't `p392` parsing the JSON data correctly?

Comment: I get the p392 behavior in 2.0.0 also, so this must be an intended change.

Comment: Did I miss anything obvious in the documentation that describes this change? I mean... it's not backward compatible...

Comment: This could be related to the recent [security advisory](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/23143553-Security-February-11th-2013-Rails-and-JSON-Vulnerabilities) and patches to Rails. It may be a very deliberate change. Allowing arbitrary instantiation of Ruby objects by default on what was thought to be a neutral data-only transport method was never a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure why/what changed, but I found a work-around. Basically, you need to construct a `Parser` object and pass in the `:create_additions` option, instead of just calling `JSON.parse`.

Example:

```
p = JSON::Parser.new(json_string, {:create_additions => true})
result = p.parse
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, it sounds like the recent change to the way JSON objects are unmarshelled.  I ran into a very similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163888/strange-json-behavior) and got a great answer.

Comment: Ahhh. That's very helpful. Makes a lot more sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

JSON by itself will return a hash. There is an extension to it that gives it added capability. Try using:

```
require 'json'
require 'json/add/core'
```

I think at one point in past Rubies JSON automatically loaded the extensions but that was dropped for comparability with the JSON spec.

"add/core" includes some `to_json` methods to base objects and might add the capability to recover custom objects. I ran into a similar situation passing regular expressions via JSON and that was the fix.

I'm not near my computer so that isn't confirmed, but it might help.

Comment: I think it was also dropped because it's absolutely insane to load arbitrary Ruby structures out of JSON data.

Comment: I agree with that 100%. I add a `to_h` method to create a hash for my classes that will go across the wire, and then set up `initialize` to take a hash to recreate the object on the other side.